# CORDOVA / PHONEGAP ON ANDROID 5.1 after background mode restarts always from INDEX

Tags: android, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, phonegap-build, application-restart

i have a problem with my hybrid app developed with cordova / phonegap (it not yet published..it is in test phase). As the subject of the post , if i test my app on my NEXUS 5 with ANDROID LOLLIPOP 5.1 and I put my app in background mode , when I clicked on the box in background, it restart ALWAYS from INDEX.HTML . In this regard , I tested the cordova starting app( the one with the message on the screen DEVICE READY ) and I added some more pages that I browse ( as index.html , test.html , try.html ) . The behavior is exactly the same :-( . Does anyone know help me out about it? It might be some problems with the new Android WebView System ? I tried to remove updates and uninstall it , but the behavior does not change .

Everything works correctly on all versions of IOS and on all versions 4.xx of Android. (I have not tested this behavior on lollipop 5.0)

I have used  cordova 3.7 or 4. (same behavior)

thanks in advance

Comment: I have a Nexus 4 with Android 5.1 and a cordova app I'm building and I do not have this problem.

This may be a Nexus 5 quirk but you need to test it on Android 5.1 but not on your Nexus 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... unfortunately the emulator for Android 5 or 5.1 is very slow . I tried also genymotion but the behavior is the same. Do you have any ideas on how to make this test without a device ?

Comment: Use another device. It's the only way to test it.

Comment: Finally I was able to test the application on the emulator Android 5.1 and everything works properly. Even Android 5.0 emulator.The only differences between emulator and my device is in the KERNEL and BUILD version.

The emulator that works fine, have this features:

KERNEL
3.4.67-01422-gd3ffcc7-dirty
dirty@tyrion.par.corp.gooogle.com#1
Tue Sep 16 19:34:06 CEST 2014

BUILD number
sdk_phone_armv7-eng 5.1 LKY45 1737576 test-keys

Instead my Nexus 5, have this version:

3.4.0-g8a80a0e
android-build@vpbs1.mtv.corp.google.com#1
Thu Feb 5 04:14:26 UTC 2015

BUILD number
LMY47I

Comment: Any idea about the problem ?

Comment: I'd uninstall the app, uninstall the latest webview and try that. I might even do a phone reset. Are you sure you're installing the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. Among the **Developer options** there was the 43rd option enabled >:( " **APPS - Do not keep activities: Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it**" . For this reason my cordova app after background mode, restarted always from index. Thanks for the help.